# requestFrameAnimation is choppy using duration

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm writing a fadeIn function for an HTMLElement, the animation works but it's a bit choppy at the moment. what it does is animate a fadeIn from 0 opacity to 1, it also animates over a duration using requestFrameAnimation that's why it's probably so choppy, can someone help me make my animation run more smoothly. and example is on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/XQeVev?editors=0010) look at the header fadeIn and see what I mean

```js
fadeIn: function(duration) {

    var el = this.$el,
      duration,
      end = 0;

    el.style.opacity = 0;
    el.style.display = "block";

    var step = function() {
      var current = +new Date(),
          remaining = end - current;
      if(remaining < 60) {
        if(el) {
          end = current + duration;

          var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
          if (!((val += .1) > 1)) {
            el.style.opacity = val;
          }
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(step);
    };

    step();
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smoothest one you can do is using CSS transition. But if you want to do with pure Javascript, you can do something like this

```
function fadeIn(dom, duration) {
  let start = null;

  const step = (end) => {
    if (start === null) start = end;
    let dt = end - start;
    dom.style.opacity = Math.min(1, dt / duration);
    if (dt < duration) requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

function fadeOut(dom, duration) {
  let start = null;

  const step = (end) => {
    if (start === null) start = end;
    let dt = end - start;
    dom.style.opacity = Math.max(0, 1 - dt / duration);
    if (dt < duration) requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

fadeIn(document.getElementById('your_dom'), 2000);
```

Comment: the paraemter dt is always a high number so the animation never works it just goes straight to 1 for opacity

Comment: @ONYX, dt is higher, but it divides by duration which is also high.

Comment: ok cool I got your code to work by pasting it in but now how do you do the oppposite and fadeOut